# React-Native Change selectTextOnFocus keywords (Select, Select All, Paste)

Tags: ios, react-native, textinput

In my react-native app (only iOS), currently I have some TextInput. When I select text (while holding finger on textinput), the default iOS "popup" appear.

I would like to change the keyword to match the user language of the app.

So in the screenshot below, I would like to change these keywords: Select, Select All, Paste to match the user language.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These keywords: **Select, Select All and Paste** works according to the language of the iphone/ipad. These are the defualt keywords of the **IOS** product and you can't change these according to the language selected by any user inside any of the app.

These keywords have nothing to do with the language selected by user in any of the application rather it is related to the language of the product.

Comment: I have already tried and the device language doesn't change anything :/

Comment: If this is during development I get those texts to change language by changing the "Localization native development region" from the targets properties but I'm not totally sure how to check everything works correctly for the end user when the app is published.

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers yes you are correct. I just checked it, changing device language will change these only in apps that are by default ios apps like Notes, Messages etc. Will let you know about how to change language in any application.